# Using Javascript to get weekday & highlight text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to highlight the current day of the week `span` for store opening times.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="monday">Mo&nbsp&nbsp</span>8:00 - 12:00, 14:30 - 17:00
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="tuesday">Di, </span><span class="weekday" id="thursday">Do&nbsp&nbsp</span>8:00 - 12:00, 15:30 - 19:00
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="wednesday">Mi,</span> <span class="weekday" id="friday">Fr&nbsp&nbsp</span>8:00 - 13:00
    </li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Answer (score 0):

Ah you need current day to be highlighted. Just saw your update.
I don't think html will be efficient.
You could do it in either ways as below. Hope it helps.

**JS Only:**

```
    var now = new Date();
    var days =  ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'];

    var today = days[ now.getDay() ];
    document.getElementById(today).style.background = '#FFFF00';
```

**With CSS, JS & Jquery:**

Create a class with highlight color.

```
    .highlight
    {   
         background-color:#FFFF00;  
    }
```

In document ready you could find the current day and use ID to assign this class to particular span.

```
    var now = new Date();
    var days =  ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'];


    var today = days[ now.getDay() ]; //code to assign todays day to variable
    $("#"+today).addClass("highlight"); //Jquery
```

Comment: @5parc Ofcourse not.  OP updated question with current day. Before it was for all days of week. Hence provided 2 different ways.

Comment: @sugadaddy Great Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) if you're going to do a lot of date time stuff. Then you can easily do the following:

```
var today = moment().format('dddd'); // Tuesday
today = today.toLowerCase();
var day_ele = document.getElementById(today);
day_ele.className += " highlight";
```

You'll have to do the css for the highlighting and attach it to the class of course.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure of your li's a bit so it becomes easier for me to highlight every day separately. I am using a bit of jquery to tackle this problem.

My code will check for the day number (Where sunday is 0 and saturday is 6) And will add a class to the corresponding day span.

```js
var today = new Date().getDay();

$("#" + today).addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight{
  background:#FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="1">Mo </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="2">Di </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="weekday" id="3">Do </span>
     </li>
    <li>
      <span class="weekday" id="4">Mi </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="weekday" id="5">Fr </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Those are invalid HTML IDs.

Comment: I know they are invalid ID's, I was going to point out that its not recommended / invalid to use numbers as ID's, but I was trying to keep my solution simple. I also believe that Sunday is 0 if you `new Date().getDay()`

Comment: I edited my comment. I apparently forgot how to count. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript solution:

```
function highlightCurrentWeekday() {
  var weekdays = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
  var currentWeekday = weekdays[new Date().getDay()];
  var span = document.getElementById(currentWeekday);
  span.classList.add('highlight');
}

window.onload = highlightCurrentWeekday;
```